# Find the limit as $x \to 0$ with integral from $0$ to $x$ of $\cos(t^3)/(t+x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x} dt$$

Can we use that $\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}$ ~ $\frac{1}{t+x}$ at $0$ and take this integral to be $\ln(2x) - \ln(x)  = \ln 2$?

The given answer is $\ln 2$

Comment: What have You tried?Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: First find $\int_0^x  \frac {\cos t^3}{t+x} \mathrm dt$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, we can't solve this integral. I know that does not convergense at 0

Comment: @PeterMelech, i tried to use L'Hospital rule multiplying and dividing by x. Can u give me the help of first step?

Comment: When providing clarification, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I think that's a good idea, somehow more formally for $x$ small enough there is an $\varepsilon>0$ so that $1-\varepsilon\leq \cos(t^3)\leq 1$ for $t\in [0,x]$ and therefore 
$$(1-\varepsilon)\int_0^x\frac{1}{t+x}\leq \int_0^x\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt\leq\int_0^x\frac{1}{t+x}dt$$
and of course for $x>0$
$$\int_0^x\frac{1}{t+x}dt=\ln(2x)-\ln(x)=\ln(2)$$ and thus
$$(1-\varepsilon)\ln(2)\leq \int_0^x\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt\leq\ln(2)$$
 but since $x$ could be chosen arbitrarily small ($x\rightarrow 0$), $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily small and thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_0^x\frac{\cos(t^3)}{t+x}dt=\ln(2)$.